# List of ip address bind to the given URL

Tags: linux, freebsd

How to find the list of all IP address bind to the given URL using Linux command/tools.

Comment: May I refer you to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Your question might be not enough precise (what if the server is proxying another server?)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trying to find "list of IP addresses bound to a url", I assume you are trying to enumerate the DNS entries of a domain. Then try `dnsdict6`. Of course, there are various other tools too, but I prefer this one.

It is a command line tool which lists all the subdomains or DNS entries of a any domain name provided. It can also take a dictionary file as input and also display both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of the domain.